# Insulting email from my boss who is also HR

Tags: personal-questions

> Just a quick note that I will pick up with you both tomorrow.
>
> Today if you need to go downstairs can you please refrain from parking yourselves on the radiator and discussing family issues etc and disturbing the staff, you should only need to go downstairs if you cannot discuss problems with invoices/orders over the phone.
>
> The downstairs office is not for a general walk around to stretch your legs and chit chat when you feel like it and certainly not to get a warm and stand around disturbing other members of staff.

The am building event planned

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: Are your offices so cold, that you have to go to this other place to get warm?

Comment: How is this mail insulting?? It's just your boss telling someone (maybe not you) to quit slacking in work hours.

Comment: Sounds like your boss has been had to repeat something multiple times.  The tone of that email makes me believe people are ignoring his past attempts to avoid people from hanging around "downstairs".  Hopefully, you have not been, ignoring your boss.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the question is what you should do, it seems simple. Do not go downstairs unless you really need to for a business reason, and if you do need to go downstairs, spend the minimum time there to complete the business. Attempt to use phone as much as possible.

From the "you both", it seems this was addressed to two people. You may not have engaged in all the behaviors your manager is trying to stop. For example, the other addressee may be the radiator-sitter. The main point is that your manager wants you to minimize visits to the downstairs office, and time spent there.